# Printing leading zeros in a number in C

Tags: c, numbers, digit, leading-zero

I'm working on a project and I want my program to read a strictly 5 digits number   with a leading zero.

How can I print the number with the leading zero included?
**Plus:** how can I provide that my program reads 5 digits including a zero as a leading number?

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: How do you want to input numbers in your program? Console or through a file? Give us a context for your program.

Comment: What type is the number?  Integer? Can you not just read is as a string and verify/numberify it after?

Comment: You have asked three questions (the first implied). Please don't ask several as if you are in a tutorial. If you use the format specifier `%d` in `scanf` then leading zeros are ignored. If you use the format specifier `%i` then a leading zero indicates an octal value.

Comment: If you want exactly 5 digits entered then use a string type input. The question is also unclear about "with a leading zero", must there *always* be a leading zero? Please post example inputs and required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to have input under control is to read in a string and then parse/analyze the string as desired. If, for example, "exactly five digits" means: "exactly 5 digits (not less, not more), no other leading characters other than '0', and no negative numbers", then you could use function `strtol`, which tells you where number parsing has ended. Therefrom, you can derive how many digits the input actually has:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char line[50];
    if (fgets(line,50,stdin)) {
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)line[0])) {
            char* endptr = line;
            long number = strtol(line, &endptr, 10);
            int nrOfDigitsRead = (int)(endptr - line);
            if (nrOfDigitsRead != 5) {
                printf ("invalid number of digits, i.e. %d digits (but should be 5).\n", nrOfDigitsRead);
            } else {
                printf("number: %05lu\n", number);
            }
        }
        else {
            printf ("input does not start with a digit.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On point . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to read in `int` variable. If so you can try the below solution.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int a;

  scanf("%5d", &a);
  printf("%05d",a);

}
```

Comment: This will accept from 1 to 5 digits (plus a sign) on input.  Assuming the number isn't negative, it will print the value with leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

use printf family with '%05d" to print number with leading zeros. use sscanf to read this value (leading zeros are ignored).

Consult the following code:

```
int a = 25;
int b;
char buffer[6];
sprintf( buffer, "%05d", a );
printf( "buffer is <%s>\n", buffer );
sscanf( buffer, "%d", &b );
printf( "b is %d\n", b );
```

output is:

buffer is <00025>

b is 25